# GridBagLayout and empty cells

Tags: swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I would like to know if i have to fill empty cells that i may have in my panel using a GridBagLayout.
Is there any consequence in filling empty cells with JPanel or not ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about empty cells. Leave them empty. There is absolutely no need to fill everything with unneeded components.

Comment: Costis's right. Only potential issue might be the background color of the parent panel (i.e. child components have different background color), but that's easy to fix.